# Meaning of unittest.main() in Python unittest module

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-internals

I was trying to learn unit testing in Python, specifically the `unittest` module.

Consider the following lines:

```
import unittest

class abc(unittest.TestCase):
    def xyz():
      ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I could see all my test cases running because of the call to `unittest.main()`.

I was just curious to know how this call is making all the test cases run.

I know since I'm inheriting from `unittest.TestCase` for every test class, it is doing all the magic. Any insights?

Comment: It just iterates over all subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`.  What's your question exactly?  How it finds all subclasses?

Answer (score 24):

*main* associated with *unittest* is actually an instance of TestProgram which, when instantiated, runs all your tests.

Below is the relevant code copied from the *unittest* source at *http://pythonhosted.org/gchecky/unittest-pysrc.html*:

```
735  class TestProgram:
752 -    def __init__(self, module='__main__', defaultTest=None,
753                   argv=None, testRunner=None, testLoader=defaultTestLoader):
754          if type(module) == type(''):
755              self.module = __import__(module)
756              for part in module.split('.')[1:]:
757                  self.module = getattr(self.module, part)
758          else:
759              self.module = module
760          if argv is None:
761              argv = sys.argv
762          self.verbosity = 1
763          self.defaultTest = defaultTest
764          self.testRunner = testRunner
765          self.testLoader = testLoader
766          self.progName = os.path.basename(argv[0])
767          self.parseArgs(argv)
768          self.runTests()
769
770 -    def usageExit(self, msg=None):
771          if msg: print msg
772          print self.USAGE % self.__dict__
773          sys.exit(2)
774
775 -    def parseArgs(self, argv):
776          import getopt
777          try:
778              options, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], 'hHvq',
779                                            ['help','verbose','quiet'])
780              for opt, value in options:
781                  if opt in ('-h','-H','--help'):
782                      self.usageExit()
783                  if opt in ('-q','--quiet'):
784                      self.verbosity = 0
785                  if opt in ('-v','--verbose'):
786                      self.verbosity = 2
787              if len(args) == 0 and self.defaultTest is None:
788                  self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromModule(self.module)
789                  return
790              if len(args) > 0:
791                  self.testNames = args
792              else:
793                  self.testNames = (self.defaultTest,)
794              self.createTests()
795          except getopt.error, msg:
796              self.usageExit(msg)
797
798 -    def createTests(self):
799          self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
800                                                         self.module)
801
802 -    def runTests(self):
803          if self.testRunner is None:
804              self.testRunner = TextTestRunner(verbosity=self.verbosity)
805          result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
806          sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
807
808  main = TestProgram
```

So when you execute `unittest.main()`, an object of `TestProgram` gets created which calls `self.runTests()` at line 768. The constructor also takes your current file as the default module containing the tests ( `module='__main__'`).

When `runTests()` is called, it in turn calls `self.testrunner.run()`. When you refer to the "run" method of `TextTestRunner` class, you will find that it actually runs and reports all your test results.

Test discovery is done by `TestProgram.parseArgs` at line 775 when you call unittest.main(). `self.createTests` at line 798 is actually responsible for discovering all your test cases and creating a test suite. This is all the magic.

Comment: Hangling further down you will find the loop which is used to find all test cases in `loader.py` in the methods `loadTestsFromModule()` and `loadTestsFromName()`.  It iterates over all elements in a module and applies a check `issubclass(obj, case.TestCase)` to find the test cases.

Answer (score 16):

Internally, `unittest.main()` is using a few tricks to figure out the name of the module (source file) that contains the call to `main()`.

It then imports this modules, examines it, gets a list of all classes and functions which could be tests (according the configuration) and then creates a test case for each of them.

When the list is ready, it executes each test in turn.

Comment: What is meant by internally here, can u please explain?

Comment: So, if I have couple of methods inside the class inheriting unittest.TestCases, those functions are getting called one after another, as soon as unittest.main() is invoked?

Comment: @Tyto The methods need to start with `test_` but yes. The documentation has a bunch of examples.