# How to get a class object from class name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, metaprogramming

I want to get a class reference from class object in Python. Normally I use class name as a valid reference, but it does not always work.

Consider this code:

```
import inspect
import unittest
import pywin32_testutil
mro=inspect.getmro(pywin32_testutil.TestProgram)
mro[0]
> <class 'pywin32_testutil.TestProgram'>
mro[0].__module__ + '.' + mro[0].__name__
>'pywin32_testutil.TestProgram'
pywin32_testutil.TestProgram
> <class 'pywin32_testutil.TestProgram'>
```

From the object I'm able to determine class name and using class name I can get class object. However it does not always work. Continuing the example:

```
mro[1]
> <class 'unittest.main.TestProgram'>
mro[1].__module__ + '.' + mro[1].__name__
> 'unittest.main.TestProgram'
```

so far so good, however `unittest.main.TestProgram` reference is invalid:

```
unittest.main.TestProgram
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'TestProgram' has no attribute 'TestProgram'
```

How can I work around that?

Comment: This SO answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992731/meaning-of-unittest-main-in-python-unittest-module

Comment: @amanb that behavior is not limited to `unittests` module. Tensorflow is the same  as a few others (numpy).

Comment: `mro[1]` is the *class*, you can just use it. The name of the class is `mro[1].__nam__`. I don't understand what difficulty you are encountering here. `mro[1]` *is a reference to the class*.  You can create another reference to that class using a variable, `MyClass = mro[1]`. What, **exactly** do you need?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my issue is I need to get fully-qualified class name by which I can access the class. `mro[1].__name__` returns only part of the full class name and `mro[1].__module__ + '.' + mro[1].__name__` does not always return a valid name.

Comment: ... why do you need the fully qualified name? I though you just needed the class object? What are you tryin to accomplish?

Comment: To start with, just because you have a fully qualified name for some class object, does not mean you have access to those namespaces. For example, a module `foo` can do `from .bar.baz import Foo` and then you do `import foo`, see that the fully qualified name of `foo.Foo` is `foo.bar.baz.Foo` but you cannot access `foo.bar.baz` because *you haven't imported `foo.bar.baz`*

Comment: That's exactly the issue. I get the class name, save it to DB. Some time after that process dies, I start another process, get FQCN from DB, determine the module from FQCN, load module,  and finally try to refer to a class by it's name. Which sometimes fails because FQCN is not a valid reference to class.

Comment: I know that initial import is just `import module`. So no aliases, etc.

Comment: It sounds like you need to serialize the class itself and store the serialization, not just the name, in your database.

Comment: The problem, if you look into the source code for unittest, is that they *shadow* `unittest.main` sub module by assigning to `main` in `unittest.__init__.py` by doing `from .main import TestProgram, main` where `main` is simply `main = TestProgram`. This looks on-purpose to me. In any case, you can use `importlib`, something like `mod = importlib.import_module('unittest.main')` then `mod.TestProgram`, or better yet, as @chepner suggests, *just serialize the class*.

Comment: IOW, don't try to use the FQCN as a serialization method in Python, it is not guaranteed to work, and the name-space it specifies *may have had the class removed from it*. You can always create types dynamically, i.e. using `type`, and assigning to to some other variable, i.e. `Foo = Type("Klass", (object,), {})` in which case, the full qualified name isn't going to help you import `Foo`. Or, someone can do something like `class Foo: pass`; then `Bar = Foo`, then `del Foo` and again, the FQCN is not going to help you