# What happens behind `python3 -m unittest test_module.py`?

Tags: python, python-unittest

In `test_module.py`, I define a subclass of `TestCase` consisting of several test methods.

```
import unittest

class abc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1():
      ...
    def test2():
      ...
```

I can run the test methods as test cases, by either

```
python3 -m unittest test_module.py
```

or adding to `test_module.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

and then

```
python3 test_module.py
```

In the second way, `unittest.main()` internally creates an instance of `TestProgram` which calls `self.runTests()` which creates an instance of `TextTestRunner` and calls `TextTestRunner.run()` which runs and reports all the test results in `test_module.py`. *[Meaning of unittest.main() in Python unittest module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992731/meaning-of-unittest-main-in-python-unittest-module/20993280#20993280)*.

In the first way, does the same thing happen internally behind `python3 -m unittest test_module.py`?

Answer (score 3):

The `-m` flag tells the Python interpreter that you want to use the named module as the main module to be run. It's often a strongly preferred way of running a module if it's in a package (something like `python -m somepackage.somemodule` doesn't break relative imports, while `python somepackage/somemodule.py` often does).

In this case, the `-m unittest` flag says to run the `unittest` package itself. When you "run" a package like that (or with `python localpackage/`), Python will look for a file in the package named `__main__.py`, and run that. And sure enough, the `unittest` module has a `__main__.py` file, which you can read in the [Python sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d914596a671c4b0f13641359cf43aa0d6fc05070/Lib/unittest/__main__.py). That file (after doing some housekeeping), pretty much just calls `unittest.main` with the argument `module=None`.

The `main` function (which is actually a class), figures out what to test by looking at `sys.argv`, which contains the arguments passed to Python (the ones the interpreter hasn't already handled itself). In your case, you're passing it an extra filename, after the `-m unittest` flag that tells Python what to run. So the `test_module.py` string remains in `sys.argv`, and the `unittest` code knows to load it up and checks for tests.

This is a little different than what happens when you run your test module directly. When you do that, the test module is known as `__main__` inside the interpreter. When you call `unittest.main()` without providing any arguments, `"__main__"` is the default `module` value. Thus the unittest code imports `__main__`, and checks it for tests, without needing to look at `sys.argv` (though it may check there for other command line flags).

Comment: Thanks. Do both ways in my post implicitly use `TestSuite`?

Comment: They should be entirely the same, once they get past the point of identifying the module that contains the tests.

Comment: Sorry if my last comment wasn't clear. I saw it is not possible to run test cases directly without putting them into a test suite, but forgot where I saw it and whether it refers to python's unnittest module or Java's JUnit.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622158/is-it-not-possible-to-run-test-cases-directly-without-putting-them-into-a-test-s

Comment: Yes, it turns out it does create a test suite for you automatically. But I had to read the code to find that, so maybe you should just do it yourself and cut out the middleman! Here's the whole code for the `unittest` package in the standard library: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/unittest